# Как подписаться на изменение файла в файловой системе?

Tags: php, linux, c, kernel

Хочу создать процесс, который посылал данные из файла, при изменении этих файлов. На ум приходит только, в цикле на каждом тике проверять время последней модификации файла, но хотелось бы как-то подписаться на событие файловой системы (чтобы система сама меня оповещала об этом).
Есть ли какие-либо для этого процедур

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Штука, которая Вам нужна, называется [inotify](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify). А дальше просто гуглением находятся примеры, например [это](http://man7.org/tlpi/code/online/diff/inotify/demo_inotify.c.html).

Comment: Супер, это то что надо, спасибо!